# How to monitor JBoss ports in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

How can i monitor the JBoss http port with Eclipse? When i open the monitor properties and try to add a port on the JBoss server there are no ports listed. Glassfish e.g. shows two ports there, the admin Server Port (4848) and the Server Port (8080).

JBoss AS 7.1.1, Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,this is what you want. **It is same for Jboss AS7**

[image: Eclipse Server Properties]

When you add server, double click on it. See at the right corner the ports will be shown.
If you want to add unlisted port, right click on server, select `Monitoring`, then "`Properties`" and from there, add port.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i dont have ports listed in the `Monitoring Ports` dialog like i have on Glassfish.